# Excel Index: Reference Error when using a index function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I am using Formula as:

```
=INDEX(B1:G1,H3)
```

Its not working. even tough similar posts are present I could not find the issue with this.

I am actually doing a max of all the Row entities like:

```
=MAX(B2:G2)
```

and doing

```
=INDEX(B1:G1,H2)
```

It works for first row and not for the other

Comment: The first works due to coincidence, nothing else. *6* is the maximum value and it just happens to be the position of the value you are looking for. The third row is `#REF!` because you are trying to retrieve the 8th cell within 6 cells; it cannot be found. The same goes for the fourth row with the 77th cell within 6 cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INDEX wants the relative position not the value.  You need to add a MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,MATCH(H2,B2:G2,0))
```

The Match will return the relative position of the match.

Comment: `=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,1, MATCH(H2,B2:G2,0))`

Comment: what are the meanings for 1 and 0 here.

Comment: @user11217663 with the range being one row the `,1` is not needed.

Comment: @MLLearner2 the `0` in mine make it look for an exact match.

Comment: THank you @user11217663

Answer (score 0):

Index is using H3 to determine the column to return. That is why Row1 is functioning. It is finding column 6 (between B1:G1) and returning the result. It is only happenstance that it is the correct answer. If you were to substitute 5 into cell H2 it would likewise return Column5. In the other examples shown, the max function is returning a column index which is beyond what is in the array (B1:G1 is 6 columns long).

To correct, pair Index with the Match function. Match will search the array (B2:G2; B3:G3; etc.) and return the column number of the matching column, then pass that on to the Index function to return the proper result.

Your final formula will look like this: 
=INDEX($B$1:$G$1, MATCH(H2, B2:G2, 0))